# XMPP Punjab BOSH connection manager giving 405 while using Strophe.js

Tags: xmpp, strophe

Configuration:

- Windows 7
- Python 2.7
- TwistedPython 10.2.0
- Latest Punjab on GitHub

I started Punjab from the command line with: "python c:\python27\scripts\twisted.py -y punjab.tac"

I can hit the url just fine from Chrome: http://localhost:5280. The page gives the XEP-0124 response.

While using Strophe.js though, I keep getting a "405 method not allowed" response from Punjab. I'm fairly certain its not Strophe as I've been able to connect using public Punjab deployments just fine. Perhaps something I'm missing with the Punjab configuration?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: which xmpp server are you trying to connect to ? In case its a local server, may be both punjab and the server are using the same port. Had faced such a problem myself... only a wild guess though

Comment: I'm trying to hit the GTalk server (@gmail.com)

Answer (score 2):

Forgot to put "http-bind" at the end of the url. The full url should be "http://localhost:5280/http-bind".